# HTML onchange not getting fired from Ajax insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to Jquery Ajax.
I have a jquery ajax function, which receives a value from a server.

```
function servertransfer_reg(datapack1,datapack2,datapack3,datapack4) {
    alert('Start of Ajax Call');
    //Ajax , Jquery Call to Server for sending free time data
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
        url: "xyz.php",
        data: {M_N : datapack1,
                       Em : datapack2,
                       TandC: datapack3,
                       News: datapack4
                },
        success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.appid);
        $("#server_answer_reg").html('<p>Your App ID Successfully created<p/>' + data.appid);
        //document.getElementById("partyID").innerHTML = data.appid;
        $("#partyID").html(data.appid);
       }
    });

}
```

Here, I am getting data.appid from server.
I want to insert it into an html element #partyID, and after insert I am expecting onchange event to get fired which will do some work for me.
Below is the html.

```
<input onchange="saveIDs()" type="text" id="partyID" class="none_visible" value=""></input>
```

Here, my saveIDs() function is not getting called.

I am receiving the intended data from my Ajax call.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: try this :  $("#partyID").val(data.appid); instead of using html() method.

Comment: input's do not have html they have values. Also the onchange event does not get fired when the value is changed programmatically.

Comment: I tried val(data.appid). But it did not work. Maybe because I am trying to chnage the value programatically as stated by Patrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onchange` will fire when you leave the focus from it (if you performed any changes). After the successful execution why don't you call the `saveIDs()` function in the next line? What I mean is

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data.appid);
   $("#server_answer_reg").html('<p>Your App ID Successfully created<p/>' + data.appid);
   //document.getElementById("partyID").innerHTML = data.appid;
   $("#partyID").html(data.appid);
   saveIDs();
}
```

Comment: Directly calling saveids() from sucess function worked !!!
I was unnecessarily making it difficult !!!
Thanks for the hint !!!

Comment: Glad it helped :) You may want to mark it as the answer

Comment: calling saveIDs() after $("#partyID").html(data.appid); will execute the saveID() function but <input onchange="saveIDs()" will be executed on any change in input. SO what is is the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You must `trigger` the `onchange` event.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/